# _POSIX_VERSION and setpriority()

Tags: c, posix

Which version of Posix
mandates the presence of `setpriority()` within `sys/resource.h` ?

I read "version of Posix" as in "value of [`_POSIX_VERSION` within `unistd.h`](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Standards/)".

Bonus point if there is a generic way to answer such question as "which version of posix supports feature X?", since it happens frequently enough when considering portability.

Comment: The bonus point: each POSIX compliant man page (`setpriority` [is not an exception](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority) too) shall include the revision of POSIX which the feature it describes conforms to.

Comment: Thanks @hidefromkgb ! Unfortunately, not all man pages are as complete as they should. `man setpriority` only make a brief mention of BSD 4.2 on my Mac, and for some reason, the doc I used to consult made only mention of posix 2008, which was clearly not the earliest possible conforming edition. The link you provide is much more complete !
I read it as : `_POSIX_VERSION >= 200112L`

Comment: In general OSes don't always ship up-to-date manpages... I often use the website linked above, or [man7.org](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html)

Comment: Thanks ! What about `sys/ressource.h` itself ? I'm asking as the website mentioned displays a broken page when clicking on `sys/ressource.h`, and _no_ other documentation I could find on Internet would bother mentioning any pre-requisite to test the presence of this file. And obviously, trying to include a non-existing file breaks preprocessor stage, so better have a proper test for it (even a conservative one). By default, I'm intending to use the same test as `setpriority()`.

Comment: The most comprehensive test I can think of is to check whether it is available right inside the Makefile and then pass a `#define` to the compiler if the check succeeded. `[ -f sys/resource.h ] && prio=-DHAVE_SETPRIORITY || prio=; clang $prio -O2 ./prio.c` — something like that. But my spidey sense is telling me that this is a bit overkill, and it\`s sufficient to just check if we are building for Windows.

Comment: Regarding manual pages and references, might as well go [to the official Open Group POSIX reference site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). It should be complete in regards to all things POSIX.

Comment: @hidefromkgb : yes, a build test would solve that. It can be easily added into `Makefile` for example.
Problem is, whenever the source file is integrated into _another_ build system (XCode, visual, cmake, meson, etc.), the build test will no longer be there, and preprocessing stage will fail.
So whenever possible, I try to use build macros, which do not depend on build system test.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : thanks for the link. Yes, I found that site too. Problem is, it does not mention any way to test presence of a feature. It's merely a "this is what is in latest version of the standard". For example : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_resource.h.html describes content of `sys/resource.h`, but doesn't tell how to test its presence _before_ using a `#include`.